# How to convert a Python Script constains Pyomo, GLPK, IPOPT to single exe app with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyomo, glpk, ipopt

I am trying to build a program which solves linear programming problems. I decided to use pyomo as package and glpk and ipopt as optimizers. I need to convert my Python script to single exe file. I used Pyinstaller but there is error

`pyomo.common.errors.ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'ipopt'`

How can i include glpk and ipopt solvers to single exe file along with my Python script.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it for single exe app, but there is a working solution for one directory mode of PyInstaller.

1. Firstly you should specify a path to your solver executable in your pyomo optimization settings

   `opt =  pyomo.SolverFactory('ipopt', executable='ipopt.exe')`

For this case `pyomo` will be looking for solver executable in your current directory with your Python script being runned.

2. Secondly, you may start compiling your script by `PyInstaller`.
3. Once the compilation is finished, paste solvers executables into the directory with `.exe` file.

If you are going to compile your code into single `.exe` file you can repeat that steps and compile the script into a single `.exe`. It should work with solvers executables placed in the very same directory of your single app file.

However if you are going to compile your code into single `.exe` file without any other auxiliary files, you may try to play with `.spec` file which contains settings for PyInstaller. If you have that file, it could look like

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['your_script.py'],
             pathex=['path_to_your_script'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('vcomp140.dll', '.')],
             hiddenimports=['pkg_resources.py2_warn','pyomo.common.plugins','pyomo.repn.util',
                            'pyomo.opt.plugins',
                            'pyomo.core.plugins',
                            'pyomo.dataportal.plugins',
                            'pyomo.duality.plugins',
                            'pyomo.checker.plugins',
                            'pyomo.repn.plugins',
                            'pyomo.pysp.plugins',
                            'pyomo.neos.plugins',
                            'pyomo.solvers.plugins',
                            'pyomo.gdp.plugins',
                            'pyomo.mpec.plugins',
                            'pyomo.dae.plugins',
                            'pyomo.bilevel.plugins',
                            'pyomo.scripting.plugins',
                            'pyomo.network.plugins',
                            'pandas._libs.skiplist'
             ],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='your_script',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='your_script')
```

So, you can try to include your solver executable files into PyInstaller import by adding them through `data` parameter in `Analysis`

Comment: I do not know how to say thanks! You are great! Trying to solve this took many hours from me. Thanks a lot!